# Reset table using reset button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, antd

I'm new React developer(mainly with hooks but did not find good example with hooks), here i have antd table with search functionality, my question is when user writes something in search then user gets different result, how to cancel that search by clicking 'Reset' button ?
my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-filter-search-forked-mqhcn?file=/src/EventsSection/EventsSection.js

Comment: onClick reset value of search ??

Comment: when user clicks 'Reset' button it should show everything in the table (unsetting the search done by user?)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `id` to your input into `TitleSearch.js`:

```
<Search
      id='IDYOUWANT'
      placeholder="Enter Title"
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onChange={onChange}
      style={{ width: 200 }}
    />
```

And add event into `EventsSection.js`

```
ResetInput = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('IDYOUWANT');
    input.value = '';
    this.handleSearch('');
  }
  ....
 <button
  onClick={this.ResetInput}
 >Reset</button>
```

Change `IDYOUWANT` with your id

Answer (score 1):

run this code

Created a new function for reset value and trigger it from reset button.

**function:**

```
resetValue = () =>{
        this.setState({
          eventsData: eventsData
        });
      }
```

**And trigger from button**

```
<button onClick={this.resetValue}>Reset</button>
```

all code::

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { EventsTable } from "../EventsTable";
import { StatusFilter } from "../StatusFilter";
import { TitleSearch } from "../TitleSearch";

const eventsData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: "Bulletproof EP1",
    fileType: "Atmos",
    process: "match media",
    performedBy: "Denise Etridge",
    operationNote: "-",
    updatedAt: "26/09/2018 17:21",
    status: "complete"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: "Dexter EP2",
    fileType: "Video",
    process: "Compliance",
    performedBy: "Dane Gill",
    operationNote: "passed",
    updatedAt: "21/09/2018 12:21",
    status: "inProgress"
  }
];

class EventsSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      eventsData
    };
  }

  handleFilter = (key) => {
    const selected = parseInt(key);
    if (selected === 3) {
      return this.setState({
        eventsData
      });
    }

    const statusMap = {
      1: "complete",
      2: "inProgress"
    };

    const selectedStatus = statusMap[selected];

    const filteredEvents = eventsData.filter(
      ({ status }) => status === selectedStatus
    );
    this.setState({
      eventsData: filteredEvents
    });
  };

  handleSearch = (searchText) => {
    const filteredEvents = eventsData.filter(({ title }) => {
      title = title.toLowerCase();
      return title.includes(searchText);
    });

    this.setState({
      eventsData: filteredEvents
    });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const searchText = e.target.value;
    const filteredEvents = eventsData.filter(({ title }) => {
      title = title.toLowerCase();
      return title.includes(searchText);
    });

    this.setState({
      eventsData: filteredEvents
    });
  };

  resetValue = () =>{
    this.setState({
      eventsData: eventsData
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className={styles.container}>
        <header className={styles.header}>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Events</h1>
          <button onClick={this.resetValue}>Reset</button>
          <TitleSearch
            onSearch={this.handleSearch}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className={styles.action}
          />
        </header>
        <EventsTable eventsData={this.state.eventsData} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export { EventsSection };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did in order to solve it:

i added onClick on the button

```html
<button onClick={this.resetSearch}>Reset</button>
```

Then in the function i put handleSearch to '', by doing this it reset the table:

```html
  resetSearch = () =>{
  this.handleSearch('')
}
```

Comment: With this solution you don't clear input right?